# Apache Error log with mod_fcgid process exit(lifetime expired)

Tags: apache-2.2, php

I have lots of errors in my apache error log as below, anyone has any idea why is this error ?

```
[Thu Jan 30 17:15:40 2014] [error] mod_fcgid: process /var/www/cgi-bin/cgi_wrapper/cgi_wrapper(25614) exit(lifetime expired), get unexpected signal 11
[Thu Jan 30 17:15:40 2014] [error] mod_fcgid: process /var/www/cgi-bin/cgi_wrapper/cgi_wrapper(25616) exit(lifetime expired), get unexpected signal 11
[Thu Jan 30 17:15:40 2014] [error] mod_fcgid: process /var/www/cgi-bin/cgi_wrapper/cgi_wrapper(25618) exit(lifetime expired), get unexpected signal 11
[Thu Jan 30 17:16:30 2014] [error] mod_fcgid: process /var/www/cgi-bin/cgi_wrapper/cgi_wrapper(25668) exit(lifetime expired), get unexpected signal 11
[Thu Jan 30 17:16:39 2014] [error] mod_fcgid: process /var/www/cgi-bin/cgi_wrapper/cgi_wrapper(25661) exit(lifetime expired), get unexpected signal 11
[Thu Jan 30 17:17:03 2014] [error] mod_fcgid: process /var/www/cgi-bin/cgi_wrapper/cgi_wrapper(25684) exit(lifetime expired), get unexpected signal 11
[Thu Jan 30 17:17:03 2014] [error] mod_fcgid: process /var/www/cgi-bin/cgi_wrapper/cgi_wrapper(25688) exit(lifetime expired), get unexpected signal 11
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe your php script takes too much time to finish.

Try adding these to your apache php.conf

ProcessLifeTime 7200
IPCConnectTimeout 30
IPCCommTimeout 60

Comment: do you meant php.ini file ? if so that didnt fix the problem

Comment: i still get [error] mod_fcgid: process /var/www/cgi-bin/cgi_wrapper/cgi_wrapper(25124) exit(lifetime expired), get unexpected signal 11

Comment: Nonono, into your apache's php config. Also with line breaks.